# What causes this \discretionary error?

Tags: errors, babel, hyphenation

I would like to compile my old LaTeX thesis to PDF. The text was created in 1999 (emTeX, I believe) when the computers and the tools were a bit different --  read it, I am returning to LaTeX after 14 years; that is long enough time to forget everything :) The babel was not used for Czech in the time.

So far, (after several trial/failure, digging the info from my memory, and searching a bit) I have converted the sources to UTF-8, and changed the

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{czech}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

When running the following `pdflatex --version` on Windows 7

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.16; using libpng 1.5.16
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

(and running bibtex for my.aux file, and rerunning several times the `pdflatex pri98dis.tex`, I still get the following problem reported:

```
) [141] (./pri98dis.aux (./dekuji.aux) (./abstrakt.aux)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.223 ...`\discretionary {-}{}{}step}{{3.1.5}{52}}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \discretionary 
l.223 ...`\discretionary {-}{}{}step}{{3.1.5}{52}}

A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.

! Extra \endcsname.
\@newl@bel ... \bbl@tempa \csname #1@#2\endcsname 
                                                  \def \bbl@tempb {#3}\@safe...
l.223 ...`\discretionary {-}{}{}step}{{3.1.5}{52}}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

The `[141]` is the very last page of the document. (Notice the `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` and later the `! Extra \endcsname.`)

In `pri98dis.aux` (belongs to the main document), the lines 222 and 223 look this way:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{Krok modelov\IeC {\'e}ho \IeC {\v c}asu.}{52}}
\newlabel{time\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}step}{{3.1.5}{52}}
```

It seems that it belongs to the following part of the source:

```
\paragraph{Krok modelového času.}

... text of one paragraph...

\begin{verbatim}
    in('EvQue', 'head', ?head_time);                               { 1 }
    in('EvQue', 'list', head_time, ?next_time);                    { 2 }
    out('EvQue', 'head', next_time);                               { 3 }
\end{verbatim}
\label{time-step}
```

It seems that the problem is somehow caused by the `\label{time-step}`.

How can I fix the problem?

(Thanks, and wishing you the Happy New Year, and all of the days after.)

Comment: Are you loading other packages?

Comment: it's definitely the hyphen in "time-step" that's expanding with the `\discretionary`.  @JavierBezos' question is relevant to getting to the bottom of where this is happening, but if you just want to get around it, change the content of the label (and its references) to not use a hyphen.

Comment: My suspicion is a redefinition of `\label`...

Comment: I get no error from the example and in the `.aux` file I find `\newlabel{time-step}{{}{1}}`; can you try producing a really minimal example?

Comment: Yes, I am using one package created for the document. It is apparently related to the `\label` with an identifier that contains `-`. However, I use a lot of such labels and the problems manifest only on few places. I did separate much smaller example, but it is still too big co copy here. And it is someow fragile. When removing seemingly unrelated block of the source text, the problem disappears. I will try later to make it shorter. So far, thanks to all.

Comment: Note this information is being written to the `.aux` file, so you will need to compile twice to see effects of any changes, i.e. an error may well persist one the first compilation after a change.  This may explain why the behaviour appears fragile.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks for the comment. Anyway, I am aware of that. I have always called a batch file for deleting the `.aux` file before running the `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by a package (babel language shorthand?) defining `-` to be active and then trying it to act "as normal" by defining it to be

```
\leavevmode\char`\-
```

I get almost the same error (slightly different context, but the same

```
time\unhbox \voidb@x \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}step
```

from the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`\-\active
\def-{\leavevmode\char`\-}

\begin{document}

aa \section{zzz\label{time-step}} aa

zzz\ref{time-step}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to change the macros, the simple way to avoid the error is to not use `-` in label, ref and cite arguments.