# nbconvert-generated labels fail with babel, work without it or with large margins

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, geometry, auxiliary-files, pandoc

I'm using `ipython nbconvert` (which uses `pandoc`) to transform an IPython notebook and the document code contains the following lines

```
   \subsection{Vytvářeni polí
čísel}\label{vytvuxe1ux159eni-poluxed-ux10duxedsel}
```

It compiles correctly, but when I add

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
```

I get the following error

```
[8] (./Python_NumPy.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.33 ...vářeni polí čísel}{subsection.3.1}{}}

?
```

The whole offending line in `Python_NumPy.aux` seems to be

```
\newlabel{vytvuxe1ux159eni\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}poluxed\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}ux10duxedsel}{{3.1}{2}{Vytvářeni polí čísel}{subsection.3.1}{}}
```

Oddly enough, When I change the margins via the `geometry` package to some large value the errors go away.

I suspect that the `babel` package treats hyphens in the labels as hyphenation patterns for some reason (that might be why margins may have this effect). I'm not sure how to debug this further.

Comment: I did an experiment and I can't reproduce the issue. Can you show a minimal LaTeX document that has the problem?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151804/what-causes-this-discretionary-error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by disabling shorthands with the respective `babel` package option

```
\usepackage[czech,shorthands=off]{babel}
```

I also tried disabling just the `-` character (because it is in the labels) with

```
\shorthandoff*{-}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: This is not the best way to do it, as you'll lose the benefits of the shorthand.

Comment: Yes, I'm particularly happy about it either @egreg. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: That's the reason why I asked for a minimal example.